git instaweb macos -- "No such projects found"
Trying to get git instaweb working on MacOS. Tried using webrick and installed lighttpd.
I'm able to start instaweb with both webrick and lighttpd, but when the instaweb page loads, there is a minimal screen with a search box and the message "No such projects found".
Certain that I'm doing this correctly, according to the docs, and not sure why I can't see projects.
Any guidance / advice is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Figured it out and got instaweb working. Posting here in case it saves others time and effort in the future.
It turns out that I was running an incomplete git install, meaning that I had only the git binary installed on my machine, but not the full install (which has the pieces needed to run instaweb). Also, I realised that it is sometimes necessary to run 'git init' on the repo that you want to run instaweb on top of.
So, here's what worked:

Reinstall git via brew install git. Pay attention to the relinking instructions at the end of the install process.
Run git init on the repo of interest you haven't already (ie. you're working on a cloned repo, etc.). Ask Google or chatGPT about possible negative effects of doing the init on an existing repo, for tips on how to avoid problems with this.

Hope this helps someone in the future.
